# Uncaught TypeError generated for proxy on production build

Tags: javascript, material-ui, vite, emotion

I wanted to alter MUI's `styled` function a little bit, so I created the following proxy for it:

```
import * as muiSystem from '@mui/system';

type CreateMUIStyled = typeof muiSystem.styled;
type MUIStyledParams = Parameters<CreateMUIStyled>;

...

const system = new Proxy(muiSystem, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    if (prop === 'styled') {
      const styled = Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);

      return function (...args: Parameters<CreateMUIStyled>) {
        const newOptions = getComposedOptions(args[1]);
        const newArgs: MUIStyledParams = [...args];
        newArgs.splice(1, 1, newOptions);
        const styledResult = styled(...newArgs);

        return function (
          ...newestArgs: Parameters<ReturnType<CreateMUIStyled>>
        ) {
          return styledResult(...newestArgs);
        };
      };
    }
    return undefined;
  },
});

export const styled = system.styled;
```

This worked absolutely fine while running in my Vite dev server, but blew up in my prod build:

> Uncaught TypeError: 'get' on proxy: property 'styled' is a read-only and non-configurable data property on the proxy target but the proxy did not return its actual value (expected '(o,s={})=>{n6e

I'm confused as to what would cause the code to run just fine locally but would generate the above error in prod... Is there anyway to mitigate that?

Comment: Does your local vs prod include different transpiling configuration by chance? It would be useful to see the configuration.
By the way I'd make sure the `return undefined` path returns unmodified properties e.g. `return Reflect.get(...arguments);` or `return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);` as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I've answered this question befor, so

The `receiver` argument in `Proxy#get` is *the proxy itself*

```
let foo = {}
const proxiedFoo = new Proxy(foo, {
 get(target, property, receiver) {
  console.log(receiver === proxiedFoo)
 }
}
```

And the `receiver` of `Reflect.get` is `this` to use for getter

```
function Reflect_get(target, property, receiver = target) {
  let descriptor = Object.getPropertyDescriptor(target, property)
  if (descriptor.get) return descriptor.get.apply(receiver)
  else return (receiver as typeof target)[property]
}
```

So the `receiver` of `Reflect.get` is not needed or should be `target`

Comment: If this is a correct answer please change the question name so it would be easy to find for ppl with Proxy.get/Reflect.get problem for `[typescript] proxy get error reflect` search

Comment: But why does this behaviour manifest itself only with a prod build and not locally?

Comment: Does it even run locally? (try placing `throw 'it does run'` in it to check)

Comment: It runs perfectly fine locally, hence my confusion.

Comment: I mean, does *that piece of code* actually run? If can be skipped by whatever reason

Comment: Also is node version the same?